# cordova build error in visual studio 2015

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, build.gradle, apache-cordova

I am using visual studio 2015 in windows8 .when i am trying to build a hybrid application it build unsuccessful due to  processDebugResources . I do not know why this is happening . when i am trying to build new sample app it become build successful. so am attaching my error statements below. so please help me to solve the error.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: nidhinhybrid, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: E:\VISUAL STUDIO SETUP\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.42
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Cordova tools 6.1.1 already installed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\bld\Android\Debug
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\bin\Android\Debug
1>  ------    buildCommand: build
1>  ------    platform: Android
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: android
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: nidhinhybrid
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\gopus\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  ------    gradleProxy: http://127.0.0.1:8888/
1>  ------    buildTarget: AndroidEmulator
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------ Platform android already exists
1>  ------ Copying native files from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\native\android to platforms\android
1>  ------ Done copying native files to platforms\android
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  ------ Currently installed plugins: cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.2.2
1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins:
1>  ------ Currently configured plugins:
1>  ------ Preparing platform: android
1>  Executing "before_prepare"  hook for all plugins.
1>  Executing "before_build"  hook for all plugins.
1>  Searching PlatformJson files for differences between project vs. platform installed plugins
1>  No differences found between project and android platform. Continuing...
1>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
1>  Found "merges" for android platform. Copying over existing "www" files.
1>  Wrote out Android application name to "nidhinhybrid"
1>  Wrote out Android package name to "io.cordova.myappb16ca2"
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\icons\android\icon-36-ldpi.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\icons\android\icon-48-mdpi.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\icons\android\icon-72-hdpi.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\icons\android\icon-96-xhdpi.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  splash screens: [{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png","density":"land-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-xhdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png","density":"port-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-xhdpi","platform":"android"}]
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  updated project successfully
1>  Executing "after_prepare"  hook for all plugins.
1>  ------ Copied C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\bin\Android\Debug\VSBuildInfo.xml to platforms\android\assets\www\VSBuildInfo.xml
1>  ------ Building platform: android
1>  Debug
1>  ------ Build configuration options: --debug
1>  Executing "before_compile"  hook for all plugins.
1>  ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
1>  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101
1>  Reading build config file: C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\build.json
1>  :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
1>  :preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
1>  :checkDebugManifest
1>  :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:compileLint
1>  :CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
1>  :CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
1>  :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
1>  :CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
1>  :prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
1>  :prepareDebugDependencies
1>  :compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
1>  :compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
1>  :generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
1>  :generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
1>  :mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
1>  :generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
1>  :generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
1>  :mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
1>  :processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
1>  :processDebugResources FAILED
1>
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
1>  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
1>
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * What went wrong:
1>  * What went wrong:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
1>  Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
1>  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
1>
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * Try:
1>  * Try:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
1>  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
1>
1>  BUILD FAILED
1>
1>  Total time: 5.92 secs
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
1>  Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1    nidhinhybrid        1
Error       FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.    nidhinhybrid        1
Error       * What went wrong:  nidhinhybrid        1
Error       Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'. nidhinhybrid        1
Error       * Try:  nidhinhybrid        1
Error       Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.  nidhinhybrid        1
Error       Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "C:\Users\gopus\documents\visual studio 2015\crossplatform\nidhinhybrid\nidhinhybrid\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true" nidhinhybrid        1

Comment: please help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

When you build/generate ***.apk** file, *.gzip, etc file cannot package. This file are occured by using bower or other related package manager. So, we need to delete this kind of file in your project. :)

For example Search *.gzip under your project structure.

Solution of 'processDebugResources' Exception

[image]

Answer (score 0):

THIS works for me
put all images inside one folder itself.this problem is related to images. when i paste all my pictures in one folder problem cause.so step by step i removed some pictures.it solves the problem.i think may be some of the images downloaded from internet makes the problem mainly the icon images .extensions are .png and .jpg then also it cause problem.at last i removed icon images from the folder it solves the problem. so if u identify and remove the images makes problem then your problem may be solved